# Cocoa WebView triggers double entry in text input boxes

Tags: cocoa, webview

I have a WebView into a NSViewController and I load a simple local HTML page that only has an input box or a text area.

When I write into that element, everything I type is doubled. I can't figure why this happens.

The bug is also mentioned at https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=2935794

This is how I show the WebView.

```
vc = [[NSViewController alloc] init];
webView = [[MyWebView alloc] init];
vc.view = webView;
popover = [[NSPopover alloc] init];
[popover setContentSize:NSMakeSize(320.0f, 480.0f)];
[popover setContentViewController:vc];
[popover setAnimates:YES];
id cview = [[[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow] contentView];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"index.html"];
[[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
[popover showRelativeToRect:[cview bounds] ofView:cview preferredEdge:NSMaxXEdge];
```

The HTML file the WebView is opening.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <textarea width="200"></textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how about a code sample? Why are you referring to a bug in Adobe ??

Comment: They run in the context of a WebView! That bug manifests itself only in the context of a WebView. So I'm assuming that the WebView is the issue.

Comment: What does the html content look like ?